# Can't import xml encoding WINDOWS-1256 to DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have xml file exported from legacy system encoding WINDOWS-1256
I want to import it to datagridview using c# .net framework winform
.

```
 string str = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);        
 System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(str);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(sr);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = ds.Tables[0];
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

here the result
[image]

here the first rows in the xml file :
[image]

Comment: Looks like code is defaulting to ASCII encoding.  Try UTF-8 : string str = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: i tried that but same result

Comment: It is not windows 1256.  There are arabinan characters in the file.  Open file with Notepad.  Then use menu File : SaveAs.  The encoding will be shown in the SaveAs Dialog box.  Use same encoding as the Dialog box.  I think it should be Unicode but not sure.

Comment: sure , it's an arabic data our encode is ANSI . when i used Ansi encode no benefit

Comment: The use of StringReader causes this problem.  By that time the encoding is already messed up since File.ReadAllText() has no chance to guess at the encoding correctly.  Get rid of both, use a FileStream so DataSet.ReadXml(Stream) can figure it out from the content.  Using a lot less memory is another nice benefit.